# Attach image and send it via json in base64 encoding

Tags: javascript, json, forms, image, base64

I need to create the ability to attach pictures and send them via JSON in `base64`.
But I can't get the resulting string from FileReader object. I will be very grateful if you can tell me how to fix this.

```html
<form>
    <label>Picture
         <input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" name="picture" required>
    </label>
</form>
```

```js
async function push() {
// some other actions here
    let form = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
    let json = construct_json(form);
//calls  of other functions
}

function getBase64(file) {
   let reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () { // I think there is a mistake here.
     reader.result;
   };
}

function construct_json(form) {
    let json = {
        picture: getBase64(form.get('picture')),
    };

    return JSON.stringify(json);
}
```

**UPD:**
If I'm trying to use json in the push() function then I get the same problem. And adding await doesn't help. I would be grateful for a hint how  can I display json in the push() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the answer based on comment. you can refer to the example on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-leavitt-3ne3d?file=/src/index.js:521-700)

Please add create a promise to avoid callback hell. Here I have promised the base46 Function. [Promisification](https://javascript.info/promisify)

```
const getBase64Promise = function (file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getBase64(file, (success,err) => {
        if(err) reject(err)
        else resolve(success);
    });
  });
};
```

Like this

```
async function construct_json(form, callback) {
  let data = await getBase64Promise(form.get("picture"));
    let json = {
      picture: data
    };
    return json;
}
```

Comment: In the case described in this answer, json would be undefined, right? And we can only display it inside `await construct_json(form, data => { return data; });`
What if I want to use it further down the code? Is it not possible at all?

Comment: You can use Promise to avoid callback hell

Comment: Welcome! Have a great day!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You are making a mistake when reader.onload method gets envoke. [You can find example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/FileReader#Example)

You forget to addEventListener and callback when upload gets done. Please add the following code

```
window.addEventListener("change", push);

function getBase64(file, callback) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    // console.log(e.target);
    // I think there is a mistake here

    callback(e.target.result);
  };
  reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    return e.target.result;
  };
  return reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

async function construct_json(form) {
  await getBase64(form.get("picture"), data => {
    let json = {
      picture: data
    };

    return JSON.stringify(json);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, the resulting string is still not displayed in JSON. Is there something else wrong with this code?

Comment: Now result is "undefined".

Comment: Okay. Will create a sandbox for it.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-leavitt-3ne3d?file=/src/index.js

Comment: You forgot to add Change event listener too. Please, Check the sandbox. :). I 'll upload in the answer too. Thank you, Helen

Comment: Thank you so much. This sandbox is very handy. But I tried to print json to the console and it is still empty. This is so strange.

Comment: Please try it on the sandbox.  I 'll correct your code.

Comment: Yes, I tried it on the sandbox. But I didn't get results. Maybe this is because of asynchrony.

Comment: Please, Check sandbox now ;)

Comment: Please, Actually you weren't getting any callback from reader.onload function. Your welcome.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I have one last little question. If I try to use json in the `push()` function then I get the same problem. And adding await doesn't help. Do you know how I can display json in the `push()` function?

Comment: Not a problem. Just add return before getBase64 function.

Comment: What do you mean? Add return to function `construct_json`?

Comment: Hello, Please Check sandbox now and update question. I ll post new answer accept that too ;)

Comment: Did Sandbox helped you ?

Comment: I am still getting undefined instead of json(

Comment: You can do operation inside the callback function.